# Why aren't graphics showing correctly in X-COM: Apocalypse?

Tags: x-com-apocalypse

Using [a guide](http://www.xcomufo.com/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t841.html), I've installed *X-COM: Apocalypse* on Windows XP in a VMWare instance using VDMS.

I can hear the game music playing but cannot not get any graphics to show. I'm getting some graphical response: the DOS text fades to green and if I exit by pressing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, it fades back to white text.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running it with dosbox instead of vmware? You might get better results. Also, I've had good luck with Win 7 running old games that wouldn't work in xp or vista.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that VMWare don't support your graphic card. VMWare does not allow you to customize the graphics card, but you can just dedicate some graphics memory to the vmware machine which will eb taken from your RAM and not your Graphics Memory.